# How to fill an intermediate table?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I have Two tables in ManyToMany relation:

**Table Molécules:**

```
id  | main_name | others …
--- | --------- | ------
1   | caféine   | others …
```

**Table jsonTextMining:**

```
id | title  | molecule_name                       | others …
---|------- |-------------------------------------|------
1  | title1 | colchicine, cellulose, acid, caféine| others …
```

and  1 intermediate table:

**Table json_text_mining_molecule** (it's an exemple i don't succeed to fill it):

```
json_text_mining_id      | molecule_id
------------------------ | ---------------
1                        | corresponding molecule id's
1                        | corresponding molecule id's
2                        | corresponding molecule id's
```

My problem is that `molecule_name` in `jsonTextMining` are a string, i need to separate them before anything.

I tried this :

```
$molecules = explode (', ', $jsonTextMining→getMoleculeName());
foreach ($molecules as $molecule) {
$jsonTextMining->setMolecule($molecule);
}
$em->persist($jsonTextMining);
$em->flush;
```

But i think i should loop on jsonTexMining too and to be honnest i'm not sure where to put this part of code. Is it on a random page and the code will execute, should i do a button ?

I know exactly how to fill table with id's when there is a OneToMany relation, i use `sql` like this :

```
UPDATE table1 SET id_relation1 = table2.id
FROM table2 
WHERE table1.main_name = table2.main_name
```

But this code fill only one column with id and there's always the matter of string. Is there really a way to get these id's linked so every molecule will have several jsonTextMining ?

Comment: Please @Magnus tell me how you edit my tables i tried to do the same as code 4 spaces but it didn't worked

Comment: It was because you had the character `-` in front of your table names. `-` will be parsed as a list and you can't have code blocks like that inside lists.

Comment: oh, great so i understand why you put table names in bold thx i'll do it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first split the string using regexp_split function:

```
select id, regexp_split_to_table(molecule_name,', ') as m_name from jsonTextMining
```

That will give you a table of ids and names:

```
 id |    name
----+------------
  1 | acid
  1 | caffeine
  1 | cellulose
  1 | colchicine
```

Next, you can read from the above, match the names to the ids in the molecule table and aggregate the ids. All put together would result in this:

```
select s.id, string_agg(m.id::text, ', ') 
from (select id, regexp_split_to_table(molecule_name,', ') as m_name 
    from jsonTextMining) as s, molecules m 
where m.main_name = s.m_name group by s.id;
```

Which gives this result:

```
 id | string_agg
----+------------
  1 | 4, 1, 3, 2
(1 row)
```

If you don't want to aggregate the results and display them one row per molecule then just get rid of string_agg and the group by:

```
select s.id, m.id
from (select id, regexp_split_to_table(molecule_name,', ') as m_name 
    from jsonTextMining) as s, molecules m 
where m.main_name = s.m_name;
```

Comment: Great, how can i get this result in multiple rows ?

Comment: @Gy0m  The above query works for as many rows as you like. Are you still having issues?

Comment: I edited the answer to show what to do if you wanted one row per molecule id.

Comment: Yes i was trying so long time on that one thx. I passed your answer to accepted :)